# How to fix bulma css making single column layout after breaking at point of 768 where it should have been 2 column layout for tablet devices?

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I am trying to make a layout with bulma css and It is making a 1 column layout after breaking at 768,which is tablet mode, where it should have been 4 column layout at this point, which is not the case here. So how I can make a column layout into perhaps 3 column layout and then into 2 column layout and then one column layout for mobile.

I have tried some googling and even stack overflow but I am not able to fix the problem. I have also tried giving section on the top of columns but didn't worked.

This is the basic column code from bulma css website and it is not what I want.

First column
    
    
        Second column
    
    
        Third column
    
    
        Fourth column

I am getting from 4 column layout to 1 column layout where it should be 4 column layout and then 3 column layout and then 2 column and then 1 column layout.
Edit: I want to make it work with wordpress but I can't if I can't solve this issue.

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Comment: Thanks @aidi I have it working :) , I will post the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded the solution and it is that this code is working fine for me and as I want it to work.

```
<div class="columns is-multiline  is-variable is-4">

    <div class="column is-4">
<div class=" ">

    <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <img src="myImage" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
    </div>

    <p class="subtitle is-3 card-content has-text-centered">Subtitle 3</p>
    <p class="card-footer-item">hyee</p>
</div>
        <hr >
    </div>

</div>
```

And I have made it works in wordpress by just putting the same structure in same order but wordpress way